# I can't set up Kubernetes in Centos 7: Unable to update cni config

Tags: docker, centos, kubernetes

I am trying to follow docs to setup a one node Kubernetes cluster with Centos 7.

kubeadm init will return no error but kubectl get nodes will return:

```
NAME      STATUS     AGE       VERSION
[MY_IP]   NotReady   22s       v1.6.4
```

system log repeats:

```
Jun  6 16:21:48 localhost kubelet: W0606 16:21:48.064388   11520 cni.go:157] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Jun  6 16:21:48 localhost kubelet: E0606 16:21:48.064537   11520 kubelet.go:2067] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

I can only find info about this in Kubernetes github logs but they talk about a  bug and I haven't found a workaround. Thanks

Comment: did you install flannel cni ? if not install it from here https://github.com/coreos/flannel/tree/master/Documentation  kube-flannel-rbac.yml & kube-flannel.yml

Comment: Executing "kubectl apply -f https://github.com/coreos/flannel/tree/master/Documentation/kube-flannel-rbac.yml" I get "error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 301: mapping values are not allowed in this context". Is that how I should install them? Thanks

Comment: It seems installing flannel CNI did... I had to do it from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run this command

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a pod network. Have you completed step 3 in the guide [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)? If you install one of the network overlays (listed at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/), you should be good to go.

Comment: What version of kubernetes are you running?

Comment: Version 1.6.4 on Centos 7

Comment: Perhaps try running: `kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube-1.6` instead of what you did, since it looks like using git.io/weave-kube is for older versions of kubernetes (1.5).https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kube-addon/